# Using Swift, can I use Archives to Encode an Object then instantiate that Coder/Graph on different OS X Comptuer?

Tags: swift, archive, nskeyedunarchiver

Using Swift, I can use Archives to write the instance of a class, an object, out to a graph/tree. Later I can read that serialized object from storage and reinstantiate the original object.

Question: Can I transfer that "object" across a wire to another/different computer and rebuild the graph/tree?

Yes, I want to serialize. Take an archived instance of a graph of objects to make it run on a different OS X machine. The graph arrives on the computer B, reverses the archive of the graph, and then runs without having to modify the graph or objects too much.

Question: Do they have to be only data objects? Can I send Class function information with them across the wire?

I ask because I don't want to bang my head on the desk if this is know to fail for some reason.

(Wow, I would have done better tags but not allowed to for a while)

Comment: Try it. Create a small test program to write a file and read a file. Run the write portion on one computer/iOS device. Transfer the file as needed. Run the read portion on another computer/iOS device. `NSKeyedArchiver` and `NSKeyedUnarchiver` make this simple.

Comment: Thank you for responding @maddy.  The broader answer I am searching for is input on Alan Kay's OOP with messages, "tiny little computers sending messages back on forth."

Comment: My messages would contain graphs/tries of objects to answer the problem versus explain the answer to the question (please think beyond HTML/JAVA/...) I want to know if anyone else is thinking about how to do elegance versus throwing another thousand monkeys at the problems.

Comment: This site is for asking concrete programming questions. Perhaps your question is better suited for https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com. Check their help to be sure your question suits their site.

Comment: Thank you @Maddy (strange lower limits on comment length. I am starting to remember why I left software in the first place.)

Comment: @rmaddy when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Comment: @gnat Agreed. I assumed the OP would delete this question after posting elsewhere.